# IOS 11 breaks (ionic) app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, debugging, ionic-framework

I recently updated my IOS to 11 beta 3, to make sure my ionic app would still work.

However it crashes almost right away with a black screen when I launch it.

I try to debug it with Xcode, however when I build to run it on my iPhone and catch the error, the "running on device" gets stuck on the following :

[image: Xcode error]

What can I do with this? I'm stuck with an app doomed to die once ios11 gets released, anyone could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is normally caused due to wk web view plugin. Try removing the plugin and run again

Comment: Oh my... Yes that was it! This plugin seems to be the problem with IOS11.
However, won't removing it lower the performance of my app on ios?

Comment: From my experience that plugin caused only problem.